# Как правильно: "проведение соревнования" или "проведение соревнований"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "проведение соревнования" или "проведение соревнований"?

Comment: Знание контекста было бы не лишним.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о проведении соревнования, то правильно "проведение соревнования", а если о проведении соревнований, тогда "проведение соревнований". Если неизвестно, о чём идёт речь, тогда на Ваш вопрос ответить нельзя.

Галина, Вы можете воспользоваться кнопкой "править вопрос" и уточнить содержание текста, в котором встретилось это выражение. После этого мы сможем точнее ответить на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Предпочтительно множественное число: *проведение соревновани**й**.*

[Вот](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x) что говорит Грамота:

> 2. ***обычно мн.:*** соревновани**я**, -ни**й**. Спортивная встреча для установления первенства по какому-л. виду спорта; состязание. *С. по плаванию. С. по фигурному катанию. С. в беге.*

Как правильно заметил grizzly, то, что я написал, касается только спортивных состязаний.

Comment: Там ещё есть другое значение этого слова. Лучше бы уточнить, что Ваш ответ подходит только для спортивных соревнований, а для всякого рода конкурсов будет наоборот.

Comment: Мне кажется, что если в случае с конкурсами и применяется этот же термин, то используется он так же (во множественном числе). А можете привести пример, где наоборот?

Comment: Например, *соревнование за звание "Лучший участник форума"*. Здесь в обычном контексте будет единственное число, если только речь не идёт о нескольких таких соревнованиях в разное время или на разных форумах.

Comment: *Здесь в обычном контексте будет единственное число...* Откуда такая уверенность?

Comment: Уверенность носителя языка. Это выражение встречается довольно часто в хороших источниках.